# Google Forms Date Field gets unformatted on Chrome

Tags: google-forms

**Scenario :**

- I have a Date question on a Google Forms form that shows OK (dd/mm/yyyy) on Safari (both iOS & Mac)

  [image]
- but gets unformatted on Chrome in the desktop (ddmm//yyyy) 

  [image]

**Problem :**

- is this a bug or am I missing something?

Thanks